# Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, jdbc, lookup

I am developing a Web Application in java, deployed in a WebLogic server. I have the server created with the datasource to an oracle database that works fine.

In the other side, I have the WebApplication that I can´t deploy in the server. When I clic in the button "Deploy", the following message appear in the "server log".

> Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/siam].
>   Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying
>   to lookup 'jdbc.siam' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved '';
>   remaining name 'jdbc/siam'

"jdbc/siam" -> is the name of the datasource that I want to use in my webapplication.

I hope you can help me.

Sorry for my English.

Thank you.

/*UPDATE*/
I have the connection to the database defined in the server side.

I can´t include images, but I can view the database connection in the netbeans and the name for jndi is "jdni/siam".

And in the administration console of the weblogic, I can view it as datasource with the same name.

Comment: how you are connecting to DB and description about  properties??

Comment: I create a new database connection from netbeans environment, I can view it from weblogic administration console. I include the images in the next response.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using JNDI to configure your Datasource.

Is `jdbc/siam` already configured as a JNDI resource at the server side? Here is a good start:

[Configuring and Managing WebLogic JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jdbc_admin/jdbc_datasources.html#1167286)

Hope it helps.